# Compare two select values in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my table:

**MyTable**: `Id, Title, Point, Date`

So I need to check if all points and Dates for `Title = 'member1'` is equal to  all points and Dates for `Title = 'member2'` Then `Set @flag = 1` Else `Set @flag = 0` The Exact Two Select is :

```
Select Point, Date From MyTable Where Title = 'member1'
```

And

```
Select Point, Date From MyTable Where Title = 'member2'
```

I need all rows checked if equal or not. What is your suggestion?

**Update**:

Assume the following example:

```
Title  Point     Date

T1      1   2012-04-26 07:14:34.000
T1      2   2012-07-26 07:14:34.000
T1      3   2012-06-26 07:14:34.000
T1      4   2012-05-26 07:14:34.000
T2      1   2012-04-26 07:14:34.000
T2      2   2012-07-26 07:14:34.000
T2      3   2012-06-26 07:14:34.000
T2      4   2012-05-26 07:14:34.000
T3      4   2012-05-26 07:14:34.000
T3      3   2012-06-26 07:14:34.000
T4      1   2012-04-26 07:14:34.000
T4      2   2012-07-26 07:14:34.000
T4      3   2012-06-26 07:14:34.000
T4      4   2012-05-27 07:14:34.000 -- 26 to 27
T5      2   2012-12-27 07:14:34.000
T5      6   2012-05-27 07:14:34.000
T5      3   2012-07-26 07:14:34.000
```

In this example just T1 values And T2 Values are equal and other ones are not.

Comment: What output are you looking for? How are you filtering the query? Do you want to see that t4.4 has a different date to t1.4, t2.4, t3.4. Is the missing t5.1 and t5.4 significant (and conversely t1.6 etc.) A Simple group by / count will help find gaps if you know there are 5 titles; and only 4 point 1's come out on 26.4 for example

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing you need to check that no member1's are missing from member 2 and vice versa so you will need to check both ways. If you are doing this between a range of dates (code below would be all dates) it could be done using a table of integers in a single pass and be more efficient.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
SELECT
    Point,
    Date
FROM 
    MyTable aa
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable bb
ON aa.point = bb.point
AND aa.date = bb.date

WHERE 
    aa.title = 'member1'
AND bb.title = 'member2'
AND bb.title IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT
    Point,
    Date
FROM 
    MyTable aa
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable bb
ON aa.point = bb.point
AND aa.date = bb.date

WHERE 
    aa.title = 'member2'
AND bb.title = 'member1'
AND bb.title IS NULL
)
SELECT @Flag = 1
```

Comment: that's not my answer, if any row is union between two title always return true, but I need if all rows is equal together be true and if just one of them not, or any additional row be return false. I going to update question by example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.  The plan is to get each result set, then convert it to XML and compare the two XML results.  Much easier (in my opinion).

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
[id] integer identity,
[Title] varchar(1024),
[Point] int,
[Date] datetime
);


insert into MyTable([Title], [Point], [Date])
values('T1',      1,   '2012-04-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T1',      2,   '2012-07-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T1',      3,   '2012-06-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T1',      4,   '2012-05-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T2',      1,   '2012-04-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T2',      2,   '2012-07-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T2',      3,   '2012-06-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T2',      4,   '2012-05-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T3',      4,   '2012-05-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T3',      3,   '2012-06-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T4',      1,   '2012-04-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T4',      2,   '2012-07-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T4',      3,   '2012-06-26 07:14:34.000'),
('T4',      4,   '2012-05-27 07:14:34.000'),
('T5',      2,   '2012-12-27 07:14:34.000'),
('T5',      6,   '2012-05-27 07:14:34.000'),
('T5',      3,   '2012-07-26 07:14:34.000');

-- your original queries
Select Point, Date From MyTable Where Title = 'T1';
Select Point, Date From MyTable Where Title = 'T2';

-- first I am going to just get each one as XML
SELECT [Point], [Date]
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Title = 'T1'
FOR XML PATH('');


SELECT [Point], [Date]
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Title = 'T2'
FOR XML PATH('');



-- first just get the two results into one result set
select t.FirstCheck, t.SecondCheck
from (
    select (SELECT [Point], [Date]
              FROM MyTable 
             WHERE Title = 'T1'
               FOR XML PATH('')) as FirstCheck,
           (SELECT [Point], [Date]
              FROM MyTable 
             WHERE Title = 'T2'
               FOR XML PATH('')) as SecondCheck
) as t;


-- now for the real check.

declare @flag int;

select @flag = case when t.FirstCheck = t.SecondCheck  then 1 else 0 end 
from (
    select (SELECT [Point], [Date]
              FROM MyTable 
             WHERE Title = 'T1'
               FOR XML PATH('')) as FirstCheck,
           (SELECT [Point], [Date]
              FROM MyTable 
             WHERE Title = 'T2'
               FOR XML PATH('')) as SecondCheck
) as t;
-- this should return 1
select @flag as Flag;


select @flag = case when t.FirstCheck = t.SecondCheck  then 1 else 0 end 
from (
    select (SELECT [Point], [Date]
              FROM MyTable 
             WHERE Title = 'T1'
               FOR XML PATH('')) as FirstCheck,
           (SELECT [Point], [Date]
              FROM MyTable 
             WHERE Title = 'T3'
               FOR XML PATH('')) as SecondCheck
) as t;
-- this should return 0
select @flag as Flag;
```

If I understand what you are attemptig to do, this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This will not win any beauty or performance contests but it should suffice. The gist of it is to

- Get a count of each title
- Join `MyTable` to itself on all fields you like to compare
- Join both to their respective count table
- select only results where both counts match

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH cnt (Title, cnt) AS (
  SELECT  Title, COUNT(*)
  FROM    MyTable
  GROUP BY
          Title
)  
SELECT  DISTINCT mt1.Title
        , mt2.Title
FROM    MyTable mt1
        INNER JOIN MyTable mt2 ON mt1.Point = mt2.Point 
                                  AND mt1.Date = mt2.Date 
                                  AND mt1.Title < mt2.Title
        INNER JOIN cnt cnt1 ON cnt1.Title = mt1.Title
        INNER JOIN cnt cnt2 ON cnt2.Title = mt2.Title        
WHERE   cnt1.cnt = cnt2.cnt
```